# How to tell compiler what method I am going to use if have two methods with the same names in Java?

Tags: java

How to use a method from `java.lang.Math` class if I imported static methods. I know I can just write Math.abs(-12), but are there other ways to do this?

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class Lesson1 {

  private static int abs(int x) {
    System.out.println("My abs method");
    return x;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(abs(-12));
  }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by other ways? What are you trying to do or trying to force?

Comment: One other way is using reflection, but just use Math.abs(...)

Comment: WoAiNii, I thought that anotations (@.......) is used for this. But anyway thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your custom method `abs` , call it with `Lesson1.abs(-12)`. If you want to use `java.lang.Math.abs` call it with `Math.abs(-12)` or directly `abs(-12)` cause the static import.

Comment: Thanks. I have understood that I have to use name of the class whose method I use. I have learned static import recently so I have imagine this situation.

Comment: @Vladislav You are welcome. This is the typical case why I prefer not to use static import because there is the possibility to create confusion between method names.